# Finding prime number in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am implementing in nasm program that can detect prime number that is provided.

```
    xor rax,rax;
    mov eax, 6 ;
    mov ecx, 1      ; 
loop:
    cmp     ecx, 6      
    jbe     end_loop    ;  ecx >= bufor

    xor edx ,edx ; 
    mov eax, 6 
    div ecx         ;  div dla edi

    cmp edx, 0
    je not_prime

    inc     ecx             ; i++
    jmp     loop_for
```

This is simple algorithm that checks weather 6 is prime number but it fails. It check div reminder in `edx` register. It always exit on `end_loop`(but it should end in `not_prime`) directive so program said that 6 is a prime number but it isn't. Can someone advice me how I can fix it? I have no clue.

Comment: Have you determined what is in edx when you expect it to be 0?

Comment: as far as I know edx = eax mod ecx ?

Comment: We know it's divisible by 1. Start with 2. We can determine whether a value is divisible by 2 by doing `test eax, 1`... but... take small steps, start with 2.

Comment: Oh, and if `edx` is zero, it IS prime..

Comment: Wait a minute... This says it is prime??? Is `loop_for` the same as `loop`? I suspect an error in some part you're not showing us.

Comment: Oops, meant to delete that next to last comment. I'd better go away...

Comment: `xor rax,rax` is pointless in this case. `xor eax, eax` will do the same thing and is 1 byte shorter. Remember that 32-bit instructions in 64-bit mode clear the upper 32 bits of the registers. Same with `cmp edx, 0` - you can replace it with the shorter `test edx, edx`.

Comment: `xor eax, eax` prevent me from an calculation exception. I will think about changing it. But do you have any constructive link with nasm documentation(?) another that is on nasm page it is very unreadable for me... there are not so many usefull examples.

Comment: The official NASM is everything you need. It shows you how to use the assembler, and does it very well. If you want examples of working code, search for a tutorial about assembly programming on your particular platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
  mov ecx, 1      ; 
loop:
  cmp     ecx, 6      
  jbe     end_loop    ;  ecx >= bufor
```

`jbe` means `jump if below or equal`. So what you're doing here is essentially:

```
ecx = 1;
do {
    if (ecx <= 6) goto end_loop;
```

Obviously 1 is <= 6, so it will always jump to `end_loop` on the first iteration of the loop.
That jump should probably be a `jae` instead.

---

Another problem is that you start with `ecx = 1`, since `ecx` appears to be your divisor. The first number you should try to divide by if you're checking for primality is 2, not 1.

Comment: so there should be jae and ecx should start from 2, thanks for that!